# Is there way to resolve this i was not able to get correct JSON response from my model class below provided the model class and response

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot

Model Class variables:

```
@JsonProperty("companyId")
private String companyId;
@JsonProperty("companyName")
private String companyName;
@JsonProperty("skuId")
private String skuId;
@JsonProperty("skuName")
private String skuName;
@JsonProperty("unitMrp")
private Integer unitMrp;
@JsonProperty("unitPerSU")
private Integer unitPerSU;
@JsonProperty("balance")
private Integer balance;
@JsonProperty("SUnitC")
private BigDecimal SUnitC;
@JsonProperty("SUPercase")
private Integer SUPercase;
```

Response:

```json
  {
    "SUPercase": 0,
    "SUnitC": 0,
    "balance": 0,
    "companyId": "string",
    "companyName": "string",
    "skuId": "string",
    "skuName": "string",
    **"sunitC": 0,
    "supercase": 0,**
    "unitMrp": 0,
    "unitPerSU": 0
  }
```

Comment: SUPercase and SUnitC is present in your response twice. Can you show us the full model ?

Comment: Is your code throwing any exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

you need to set visibility on class level (POJO)

```
    @JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility=JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY,getterVisibility=JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility=JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE, creatorVisibility=JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
 @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public Class Model{
    @JsonProperty("companyId")
    private String companyId;
    @JsonProperty("companyName")
    private String companyName;
    @JsonProperty("skuId")
    private String skuId;
    @JsonProperty("skuName")
    private String skuName;
    @JsonProperty("unitMrp")
    private Integer unitMrp;
    @JsonProperty("unitPerSU")
    private Integer unitPerSU;
    @JsonProperty("balance")
    private Integer balance;
    @JsonProperty("SUnitC")
    private BigDecimal SUnitC;
    @JsonProperty("SUPercase")
    private Integer SUPercase;

//Setter
//getter
    }
```